# Cache Spring cloud gateway response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

Is it possible to cache the routes' responses in Spring cloud gateway?

I have 2 routes defined

```
routes:
    - id: users
      uri: ${my_user_service.url}/users
      order: 10000
      predicates:
        - Path=/users
  
     - id: test
      uri: ${my_test_service.url}/test
      predicates:
        - Path=/test
```

Basically I would like to cache the result of the route with id 'users' in order to call my_user_service only once per user (depending on the request body)

Comment: For sure you can use Hibernate's second-level-cache (db queries), as for caching the whole requests on backend - I'd be carefull, see what http://owasp.org has to say about that..

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65498001/spring-cloud-gateway-with-spring-cache-and-caffeine